# MVC5 Passing Model to View: The underlying provider failed on Open?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm putting together a fairly simple Code-First MVC5 Inventory Tracking application. I've gotten my app to Seed() and all of my Maintenance tables (Locations, Vendors, Statuses, etc.) I can view/create/edit/delete. I'm now working on the `View` for my main [INV_Assets] model, but when I try to run the application I am receiving:

**System.Data.DataException**: `An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.`

**InnerException**: `The underlying provider failed on Open.`

The error is occurring at the below in my `HomeController`:

```
    TrackerContext _db = new TrackerContext();
    public ActionResult Index(INV_Assets defModel)
    {
        var assetList = _db.INV_Assets.ToList(); // EXCEPTION!
        return View(assetList);
    }
```

I am attempting to pass my main model [INV_Assets] to the view so that I can `foreach` through all instances in the model class and display them in a table. Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

Below I've also included my Model itself for [`INV_Assets`] and the `View`:

**INV_Assets**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using GridMvc.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Tracker.Models;

namespace Tracker.Models
{
    [GridTable(PagingEnabled = true, PageSize = 30)]
    public class INV_Assets 
    {
        // Setting GridColumn Annotations allows you to use AutoGenerateColumns on view to auto create the Grid based on the model.


        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Model_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Model_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Models Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Manufacturer_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Manufacturer_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Manufacturers Manufacturer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Type_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Type_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Types Type { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Location_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Location_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Locations Location { get; set; }

        public int Vendor_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Vendor_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Vendors Vendor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Status_Id { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Status_Id")]
        public virtual INV_Statuses Status { get; set; }

        public string ip_address { get; set; }

        public string mac_address { get; set; }

        public string note { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
        public decimal cost { get; set; }
        public string po_number { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }

        public int invoice_number{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string serial_number { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string asset_tag_number { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? acquired_date { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime? disposed_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime created_date { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string created_by { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime modified_date { get; set; }

        public string modified_by { get; set; }

        // Flag to specify if item is available? (Not signed out, not auctioned, recycled, etc.)
        //public bool available { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**[INV_Assets] View**:

```
@using GridMvc.Html
@using System.Collections.Generic
@model  List<Tracker.Models.INV_Assets>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<table style="width:100%;">

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.owner)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vendor)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.asset_tag_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.serial_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ip_address)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mac_address)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.po_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.invoice_number)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cost)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.note)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.acquired_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.disposed_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.created_by)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modified_date)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modified_by)</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

---

**EDIT**:

I have ELMAH error logging running, and after I hit continue when the Exception occurs, the log says the following:

`System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - 
Cannot attach the file 'C:\Analytic-Projects\Tracker\Tracker-DEV\Tracker\Tracker\App_Data\TrackerDBDev.mdf' as database 'TrackerDBDev'.`...?

Answer (score 1):

The one thing you didn't post was the only thing needed: your connection string in Web.config. As your database has an `.mdf` extension in the error, I'm guessing that you have deployed your project, and now cannot connect to the database. Database files like that are used by LocalDB, which is only available within the confines of Visual Studio. Once deployed to your production server, your project must use a grown-up database, like SQL Server. You just need to change your project's connection string in Web.config (or better, something like Web.Release.config, so Web.config can be transformed during the publishing process) so that it points to a full-fledge SQL Server instance containing your application's database.

Comment: Thanks for replying Chris! I had encountered something similar-ish before, and the fix was to rename the DB file in my connection string:  `[<add name="TrackerContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\TrackerDBDev.mdf;Initial Catalog=TrackerDBDev;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />]` -- [TrackerDBDev.mdf] to [TrackerDBDev-1.mdf]. Can you possibly elaborate on what causes this and why this particular action fixes the issue?